# How to use Grep | awk to get nid from Set-Cookie?

Tags: bash, curl, cookies, awk, grep

I have a trouble when using Grep and awk. I need to get the nid from the curl and i found nid located at Set-Cookie.
But when i call it, nid doesn't appear

Here the code i use

```
resp=`curl -s -i "https://xxxxxx.com/signup/account?"`
nid="("$resp" | grep -Ei0 "Set-Cookie: nid=" | awk -F[=,] '{print $1}' | xargs)"

nid = $nid
```

How to fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several syntax errors in the script.
It's also overcomplicated.
So instead of correcting every single mistake,
I suggest a simpler approach.

You don't actually need a `grep`, because `awk` can filter by itself.
A simpler and faster solution:

```
nid=$(curl -s -i "https://xxxxxx.com/signup/account?" | awk -F= '/^Set-Cookie:/ { print $2; exit }')
```

That is:

- `/^Set-Cookie:/` means to match lines starting with "Set-Cookie:"
- `-F=` is to use `=` as the field separator
- `print $2` is to print the second field. Given `=` as the field separator, this value should be on the right side of `nid=...`
- After printing, we `exit`, because we found what we wanted, no need to parse the rest of the content

Comment: Thank's a lot bro, that's work well.

Can we generate nid automaticaly using some script in bash?

Comment: if we access some website, i will generate unique nid and stored in cookie right?
My question is can that unique nid generated by self using some script?
I've read a post in website that nid can automatically generated using js. Is that true?

Comment: @AdrianBondanAdiPrakasa it seems the answer to that will depend on the specifics of the website you're using. You will find the answer in their docs.